# Pool does Not exists typeORM

Tags: mysql, node.js, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I'm using nestJS with typeorm(0.3.10,"@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.1") with MySQL. its working fine when i start the server but after one day(based on traffic) getting pool doesn't exist error. I have upgraded Typeform 0.2x to 0.3.10. based on new config I have set **`poolSize:100`** but still getting `Error: Pool does Not exists`.

when I checked DB connection used in AWS, it reached almost 100 (but traffic is not much that which consumes 100 connections).

Here is my cofigProdiver

```
export const MysqlProvider = [
    {
      provide: MYSQL_PROVIDER,
      useFactory: (tunnelService: TunnelService): Promise<any> => {
  
        return typeOrm
          .createConnection({
            type: "mysql",
            poolSize: parseInt(process.env.DB_MAX_POOL),
            entities: [...], 
            replication: {
              master: {
                host: process.env.MASTER_HOST,
                port: parseInt(process.env.MASTER_PORT),
                username: process.env.MASTER_USERNAME,
                password: process.env.MASTER_PASSWORD,
                database: process.env.MASTER_DATABASE,
              },
              slaves: [
                {
                  host: process.env.SLAVE_HOST,
                  port: parseInt(process.env.SLAVE_PORT),
                  username: process.env.SLAVE_USERNAME,
                  password: process.env.SLAVE_PASSWORD,
                  database: process.env.SLAVE_DATABASE,
                },
              ],
            },
            synchronize: false,
          } as typeOrm.ConnectionOptions)
          .then((conn) => {
            Logger.log("Connected to SQL Database");
            return conn;
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
  
            Logger.error(`Couldnt connect to Mysql ${err}`, "AppModule");
          });
      },
      inject: [TunnelService],
    },
  ];
```

Here you can see I'm using Replications, in project I have used transaction and masterRead multiple times. In each scenario, I'm releasing the queryRunner.

Here the example:

```
async update_branch_pickup_metadata(data, language) {
    const queryRunner = this.connection.createQueryRunner("master");
    try {
      await queryRunner.connect();
      await queryRunner.startTransaction();

      const updatedDelivery = await queryRunner.manager
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .update(Deliveries)
        .set({ ... })
        .where(...)
        .execute();

      await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
      return data.id
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err, "transaction error");

      await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
      throw new HttpException(
        businessErros(language, CODE_TECH_ISSUES),
        422
      );
    } finally {
      await queryRunner.release();
    }
  }
```

I have set **poolSize:100** and **released queryRunner on each transaction** but still getting `Error: Pool does Not exists typeORM`.

Here the error sample:

```
Error: Pool does Not exists.
    at PoolNamespace.getConnection (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/pool_cluster.js:37:17)
    at PoolCluster.getConnection (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/pool_cluster.js:177:15)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:724:30
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at MysqlDriver.obtainSlaveConnection (/usr/src/app/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlDriver.js:723:16)
    at MysqlQueryRunner.connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlQueryRunner.js:50:18)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlQueryRunner.js:145:55
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at MysqlQueryRunner.query (/usr/src/app/node_modules/typeorm/driver/mysql/MysqlQueryRunner.js:143:16)
    at SelectQueryBuilder.loadRawResults (/usr/src/app/node_modules/typeorm/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.js:2056:43) getOrders error
```

can anyone suggest me where I'm doing wrong because its creating lot of issue on production, I have to restart the service every day which cost lot of failure queries.

Comment: did you solve this problem?